# Sharepoint 2010 : How to upload file to custom list use REST API and javascript

Tags: 2010, rest, sharepoint-rest-api

I use Sharepoint 2010 and I create custom HTML form upload. I can some text to a normal field like Single Line of text but I do not know how to upload a file to list. I use rest API with javascript anyone knows some solution please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use SPD to open the list and go to your NewForm.aspx(or your default) and you can put your code below the "PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead".

Comment: yeah I used  but I need some javascript code about rest api upload attachment file. Now I can use rest to create text field but the attachment file is difference code

Comment: https://gist.github.com/rjsteinert/4074427

Comment: sorry Mathew How to use that resource with sharepoint custom list